# How to use ocaml-re

Tags: regex, ocaml

I am currently trying to use `ocaml-re`. Documentation is sparse. I was wondering how I would, for instance, do the equivalent: 
`Str.regexp "example \\([A-Za-z]+\\)"` using `Re.Perl`? I think it would help me to naturally get the rest of the documentation on my own. Thank you!

Bonus points if you convert this code from `Str` to `Re.Perl`:

```
let read_filename = "example.ts"
let filename = "example2.ts"

let () =
  CCIO.(
    let modify_file ~chunks = 
      let r =  Str.regexp "example \\([A-Za-z]+\\)" in
      match chunks () with
        None -> chunks (* is the same as (fun () -> None) *)
      | Some chunks ->
        let test_chunks = Str.replace_first r "\\1" chunks in (* compute once *)
        (fun () -> Some test_chunks) in
    with_in read_filename
      (fun ic ->
         let chunks = read_chunks ic in
         let new_chunks = modify_file ~chunks in
         with_out ~flags:[Open_binary] ~mode:0o644 filename
           (fun oc ->
              write_gen oc new_chunks
           )
      )
  )
```

Comment: *"Bonus points if you..."*  Please, you sound like you are giving us an assignment (and you can upvote only once).

Comment: If I could delete the question, I would

Comment: That's not a big problem, just think about it next time maybe. I think you could also edit the question, it is not a bad question.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6541726267916468224

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Re.Perl`, Re's API is much simpler. You can constructor your re with:

```ml
let re =
  let open Re in
  alt [rg 'A' 'Z'; rg 'a' 'z'] (* [A-Za-z] *)
  |> rep1a (* [A-Za-z]+ *)
  |> group (* ([A-Za-z]+) *)
  |> compile
```

Comment: Ok, just curious, what would the pipes, `rep1` , `group`, and `compile` do?

Comment: Translating to traditional regex syntax. `rep1` is `+`, `group` is surrounding with `(..)` and `compile` cannot be translated as its done implicitly by `Str`/`Pcre`, etc.

Comment: Ok, so just curious. If I may `[rg 'A' 'Z'; rg 'a' 'z']` is traditional regex syntax. What would non-traditional regex syntax look like?

Comment: I added some comments to my answer. They should explain what every step is doing in terms of PCRE syntax

Comment: Thank goodness! To be saved from the regexp arcana is a dream come true :) btw I don't see a `rep1a` in docs for the latest version. I wonder if this was depricated or maybe a type? There is a `rep1`.